# JGit - Unable to Delete .git Directory After Cloning

Tags: java, git, jgit

I'm using the following snippet to clone a single branch of a git repository to the local filesystem using JGit:

```java
public void cloneSource(Path dir) throws IOException {
    CloneCommand cmd = Git.cloneRepository();
    cmd.setDirectory(dir.toFile());
    cmd.setURI(repositoryUrl);
    cmd.setBranch(branchName);
    cmd.setBranchesToClone(Set.of("refs/heads/" + branchName));
    cmd.setCloneAllBranches(false);
    credentials.provideCredentials(cmd); // Sets authentication info for the command
    try {
        var git = cmd.call();
        git.getRepository().close();
        git.close();
        git.gc().call();
    } catch (GitAPIException e) {
        throw new IOException(e);
    }
}
```

After cloning, though, it is impossible for Java to delete files in the `.git` directory of the local repository, throwing `AccessDeniedException`, even if I shut down my original program and start it anew, or try to delete from an entirely different Java program. No other program is using those files while I'm trying to delete them.

I've read other questions which indicate the need for multiple `close()` calls, which I've done in the example, but that was apparently fixed a long time ago with [this bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=474093), but no solution found on StackOverflow has worked for me.

Alternatively, if there's no clear way to forcibly delete the files, would it also be possible to use JGit to clone the files from a specific branch of a repository, without including any of the `.git` directory's metadata? So just a way to copy all the files without any git information.

Comment: Hi @andrew , did you get solution for the above problem?

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet worked for me

```
CloneCommand cloneCommand = Git.cloneRepository();
        cloneCommand.setURI( "http://git.sample.git" );
        cloneCommand.setCredentialsProvider( new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider( "user", "pwd" ) );
        cloneCommand.setDirectory(new File("D:/Hello"));
        Git cloneGit = cloneCommand.call();
        System.out.println("Clone HEAD: " + cloneGit.log().call().iterator().next());
        cloneGit.close();
        rm(new File("D/Hello/.git"));
```

And the rm(File file) is a method that removes the file with all the subfolder and files inside recursively

```
public void rm(File f){
      if (f.isDirectory()) {
            for (File c : f.listFiles()) {
                removeRecursively(c); //recursive call
            }
        }
        f.delete();
}
```

If you are trying to do at later instance and deleteing multiple folders, try the option of

```
Git.shutdown();
```